# newcommand for verbatim

Tags: macros, verbatim

I'm trying to write a `\newcommand` for `verbatim`:

```
\newcommand{\codeline}[1]{\begin{verbatim}{#1}\end{verbatim}}
```

and use it as

```
\codeline{int foo;}
```

but it gives an error "File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim". How to fix it?

Comment: You would have to use other means to include `verbatim` content inside a macro. See [Verbatim inside a command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83893/5764). You may be interested in what the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) has to offer instead. It also provides the means to create your own environments. For example, see [Creating a custom environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85650/5764).

Comment: @Werner Thanks for your reply. Why can't I include `verbatim` inside a macro the way I did it?

Comment: An environment should be used for verbatim text. Take a loot at the `fancyvrb` package; it provides the `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment` for defining your own verbatim environment. There is also `\DefineShortVerb` for creating short verbatim texts like this `|int foo;|`.

Comment: If you don't want to use TeX stuff like `\ ` or `%` in code lines, maybe `\newcommand{\codeline}[1]{\par{\ttfamily#1\par}}` is enough?

Comment: @PaulS.: See [Why doesn’t `verbatim` work within …?](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin)

Comment: For solutions that actually use the environment, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543921/how-can-one-construct-a-macro-that-contains-a-pythontex-or-fancyvrb-environment (mostly use `\scantokens` to re-parse the tokens, is complex, but is general)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a simple implementation, go with

```
\newcommand[1]{{\small\texttt{#1}}}
```

If you want more detailed control, you should go with `fancyvrb` or `minted` packages.

Comment: Oh, btw, I like to put a `\small` in there because the default monospace font is a little too big for my taste. I like my code snippets relatively equal to or smaller than my main font.

Comment: This "dirty" command does not work for special caracters as `_`, `&`, etc. I.e. `\codeline{a_b_c}` will result in an error.

Comment: @strpeter I use the `underscore` package by default in my docs and your example works perfectly with that.

Answer (score 3):

### Specific answer

For my example below the following code from the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings) package was the solution:

```
\newcommand{\codeline}[1]{\lstinline|#1|}
```

Of course this is only reasonable if you are using short inline code examples without vertical line `|`.

### Example

MWE in which this implementation makes sense:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\includegraphicswithtitle}[1]{%
\clearpage%
\section*{\lstinline|#1|}%
\includegraphics{#1}}

\title{All graphics of my thesis}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\centering
\includegraphicswithtitle{Image08_a_1.pdf}
\includegraphicswithtitle{Image08_b_1.pdf}
\includegraphicswithtitle{Image08_c_1.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the advantage of `\codeline{text}` over `\lstinline|text|`?

Comment: @egreg: You can crop several lines together in order to reduce repeating code. Is this not advantage enough? If there is a more efficient answer, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Also note that in this case `#1` will be tokenized first (then detokenized), so `\abc\def` may become `\abc \def`, and you can't include `%` or ignored characters or multiple consecutive spaces.

Comment: Correction, it's *possible* to include special characters in \lstinline (but it needs to be appropriately escaped), read its documentation for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
\newcommand{\codeline}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
```

This will print #1 vermbatim.

Comment: From [Underscores in words (text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139980/5764)

Comment: No, from http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5539&p=21403&hilit=%5Cdetokenize&sid=ca9c653e363c550caf396b46bc68e564#p21403

Comment: note that in this case #1 will be tokenized first (then detokenized), so \abc\def may become \abc \def, and you can't include % or ignored characters or multiple consecutive spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when I tried to include the output of the Unix `cal` command inside a LaTeX macro. Enclosing the `cal` output within the verbatim environment does not work for reasons cited above.

My solution is a hack.

1. Create a LaTeX document (`calendar-out.tex`) containing only the output of `cal` and inside a verbatim environment.
2. Convert `calendar-out.tex` to png via the commands `$ latex calendar-out.tex` and `$ dvipng -T tight calendar-out`.

   Incorporate `calendar-out.png` into original LaTeX document via the `graphicx` package.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ulrich Diez's `\DefineVerbatimToScantokens` macro from the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629173/250119 (note. go to that answer to read on how to use that macro & maybe upvote if you find the answer useful. <sub>Unfortunately as far as I know it's not in any package at the moment so you have to copy paste the code</sub>), we can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

%=== Code of \DefineVerbatimToScantokens ========================
% ... <copy the code from that answer>
%=== End of code of \DefineVerbatimToScantokens =================

\DefineVerbatimToScantokens\codeline{v}{%
\begin{verbatim}
#1
\end{verbatim}
}%


\begin{document}

\codeline{int foo;}
\codeline{xy%#?!z}

\end{document}
```

Also read documentation of xparse.pdf to see what does it mean to specify `v` here and that it allows `%` etc. <sub>[except literal TAB](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508001/keyboard-tab-character-in-argument-v-xparse)</sub> to be included in the argument.

Comment: Also note that performance of this solution might be worse than \texttt solution because of the need to rescan the tokens each time it's called.