# Environment inside a command

Tags: macros, environments

My code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\QUE}[1]{%
{\bf Question\# 1 }: #1
}%end QUE

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\section{Algorithms and data structures} 

\QUE{Given the following C function definition:
\begin{verbatim}
int foo(int a, int b){
  if (a == b)
    return a;
  else
    return (a>b) ? foo(a-b, b) : foo(a, b-a);
}
\end{verbatim}
What is the result of the computation of \texttt{foo(24, 16)}?
}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\end{document}
```

Produces:

```
[...]
Runaway argument?
 int foo(int a, int b){ if (a == b) return a; else return (a>b) ? foo\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.74 \input{Q0201}
etc.
```

If I comment out `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` the code runs.
Same problem with other `\begin{something}...\end{something}`
Any hint?

Comment: You can use the `{}` button and backticks to format code in the question (see my edit)  `verbatim` environments can not be used in the argument to another command.

Comment: My advice is to *not* put `verbatim` stuff in a general macro; verbatim requires some trickery not suited to general macros.  See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86071/newcommand-for-verbatim), or the very useful [CTAN FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin).

Comment: See also the list of packages for code listing and syntax highlighting on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/topic/listing), or the list for [verbatim text](http://www.ctan.org/topic/verbatim).

Comment: Thank you very much for your illumunating response, David. Actually I wanted \usepackage{listings} and use

Comment: Thank you very much for your illuminating response, David. Actually I wanted \usepackage{listings} and use \begin{lstlisting} int foo(... \end{lstlisting}, in oder to format C code. Unfortunately the log says: Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 29.
(/usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd))
*
[...] Any more hints?

Answer (score 2):

from https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin

The LaTeX verbatim commands work by changing category codes. Knuth says of this sort of thing “Some care is needed to get the timing right…”, since once the category code has been assigned to a character, it doesn’t change. So \verb and \begin{verbatim} have to assume that they are getting the first look at the parameter text; if they aren’t, TeX has already assigned category codes so that the verbatim command doesn’t have a chance. For example:

```
\verb+\error+
```

will work (typesetting ‘`\error`’), but

```
\newcommand{\unbrace}[1]{#1}
\unbrace{\verb+\error+}
```

will not (it will attempt to execute `\error`). Other errors one may encounter are ‘\verb ended by end of line’, or even the rather more helpful ‘`\verb` illegal in command argument’. The same sorts of thing happen with `\begin{verbatim}` … `\end{verbatim}`:

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{foo}}{%`
\begin{verbatim}
foobar
\end{verbatim}
}{%
\begin{verbatim}
barfoo
\end{verbatim}
}
```

provokes errors like ‘File ended while scanning use of `\@xverbatim`’, as `\begin{verbatim}` fails to see its matching `\end{verbatim}`.

This is why the LaTeX book insists that verbatim commands must not appear in the argument of any other command; they aren’t just fragile, they’re quite unusable in any “normal” command parameter, regardless of \protection. (The \verb command tries hard to detect if you’re misusing it; unfortunately, it can’t always do so, and the error message is therefore not reliable as an indication of problems.)

So the first question to ask yourself is: “is `\verb` actually necessary?”.

```
If `\texttt{your text}` produces the same result as `\verb+your text+`,
```

then there’s no need of `\verb in` the first place.
If you’re using `\verb` to typeset a URL or email address or the like, then
the `\url` command from the `url` package will help: it doesn’t suffer from all
the problems of `\verb`, though it’s still not robust.
If you’re putting `\verb` into the argument of a boxing command (such as
`\fbox)`, consider using the `lrbox` environment:

```
    `\newsavebox{\mybox}`
    ...
    `\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}`
      `\verb!VerbatimStuff!`
    `\end{lrbox}`
    `\fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}`
```

[And so on.  More to be had in the web page at top]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. My problem is that also using \usepackage{listings} and \begin{lstlisting} int foo(... etc. Produces analogous errors. More hints?

Answer (score 1):

I have big doubts about the `\# 1` in the code, perhaps you want some space before and perhaps the `1` should be the value of some counter, anyhow, you can rescue the `\QUE` command in the following manner: (as is well explained in [wasteofspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2411/wasteofspace)'s answer, one can not put a verbatim inside what will serve as parameter to a command, so the trick here is that `\QUE` has no parameter)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% \newcommand{\QUE}[1]{%
% {\bf Question\# 1 }: #1
% }%end QUE

\newcommand{\QUE}{\textbf {Question\# 1}: \bgroup\let\next=}%

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{Algorithms and data structures} 

\QUE{Given the following C function definition:
\begin{verbatim}
int foo(int a, int b){
  if (a == b)
    return a;
  else
    return (a>b) ? foo(a-b, b) : foo(a, b-a);
}
\end{verbatim}
What is the result of the computation of \texttt{foo(24, 16)}?
}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\end{document}
```

> [image: verbatim "in" command]

Comment: naturally, one may question the whole point of the `\QUE` but I imagined perhaps the OP wants to apply some additional formating like `\itshape` to the non-verbatim part of the question. Then it makes sense to enclose the whole thing in braces creating a group. (or perhaps adjust some line spacing parameters).

Comment: Wonderful! Your changes to "\QUE" fix my problem. Your idea is right: after "Question\# ..." i put a counter. My simplification of \QUE was only for brevity. I did never use \bgroup. Thank you VERY MUCH!