# \newcommand not working ("verbatim" use case)

Tags: macros

I'm lazy and I want to save on typing.

So I have

```
\newcommand{\bv}{\begin{verbatim}}
\newcommand{\ev}{\end{verbatim}}

\bv
Hi, this should be verbatim
\ev
```

in my document, but this produces an error:

```
Runaway argument?
^^MHi, this should be verbatim^^M\ev^^M^^M\end{document}^^M
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
```

What's the matter here?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. And you shouldn't anyway.

Comment: you can not put verbatim in another command.

Comment: by its nature verbatim stops `\ev` expanding so the end of the environment is never seen.

Comment: I can't put verbatim into another command? Now I like LaTeX much less... :(

Comment: Latex doesn't care :) (I was told)

Comment: If you're ambitious and are willing to switch to LuaLaTeX (or if you've already done so...), take a look at the query [How to handle verbatim material in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361738/5001). The main answer to that query (shameless self-citation alert!) provides a way for dealing with verbatim material that's much more flexible and far less restrictive than the ways of "classic", i.e., pdfLaTeX are.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86071

Comment: If you're editing with vi, you create a three line file whose first line says \begin{verbatim}, whose second line is blank, and whose third line says \end{verbatim}, and then on each of the five-thousand occasions in your document where you want to use  this, you type a colon to get into command mode, then the letter r followed by a blank space, then the file name. It inserts the content of that file into what you're editing.