# Verbatim inline

Tags: verbatim

I'd like to put a verbatim inline. For example:

Consider the text: blah blah blah `\verbatim_inline{y = x1 + x2}` and `\verbatim_inline{y_value}`.

I tried to use `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}` in preamble, next I used `\code{y = x1 + x2}`, but a message error is showed. I tried to use `\verb`, but the equation and blah blah blah text stay together.

## Edit

```
\documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    oneside,            % para impressão em verso e anverso. Oposto a oneside
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
    % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
    chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    section=TITLE,      % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsection=TITLE,  % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    % -- opções do pacote babel --
    %english,           % idioma adicional para hifenização
    french,             % idioma adicional para hifenização
    spanish,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil,             % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    english,
    %brazil,
    ]{abntex2/abntex2}

% --
% SETTINGS

\usepackage{abntex2/abntex2-cin-ufpe}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}
blah blah blah \code{y = x1 + x2} blah blah blah. blah blah blah \code{y_value} blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does not work. I'll read about `lstlistings`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86071/194703

Comment: @WagnerJorge: Try with `\usepackage{listings}` and `\newcommand{\code}{\lstinline}`.